# Hash table where key is string and value is function

Tags: java, hash

Is it possible to have an implementation for hash, where key is `String` and value is `function`. For the background, I have a program where there is lots of string comparison, i.e.

```
if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("london")  
   functionA();  
else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("moscow")  
   functionB();  
else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("delhi")  
   functionC();  
  ...
```

and so on.

But this kind of implementation is very costly `(theta(n))`, since `String` comparison is done for all the if statements. If we have an hash implementation where key is `String` and value is `function`, we can just call something like

```
function = hash.Get("moscow");    
function();
```

Its complexity is good `(theta(log(1)))`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What language do you use? Java or C++ ?

Comment: Currently I am using java. But I think answer can be helpful for any language.

Comment: Java and C++ are completely different languages with completely different features. Pick one.

Comment: I have removed C++ from tags. Please answer specific to java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store them in a `Map<String, Runnable>`. Then with java < 8:

```
map.put("london", new Runnable() {
    public void run() { functionA(); }
});
```

Or with java 8, assuming a static method:

```
map.put("london", YourClass::functionA);
```

Or with an instance method:

```
map.put("london", this::functionA);
```

In all three cases you simply call:

```
Runnable r = map.get(input.toLowerCase());
if (r != null) r.run();
```

Comment: I can try it but just for completeness here can you add the `get` as well in case of Java 8, and how to invoke once you `get` it?

Comment: Thanks assylias, How can we call the function in your implementation?

Comment: @assylias Really, even in Java8 its same, the Map<String, Runnable>, and your example `YourClass` is a Runnable. Right? then `static`.. run() is not static right?

Comment: Not that `Runnable.run()` returns `void`. If you want the method to return something you'd use `Callable<V>`

Comment: @sakura no YourClass can be any class provided that the signature of `functionA` matches the signature of `run` i.e. returns `static void functionA()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava Function as the Hastable value in this case. 
A better way would be to use Java polymorphism and define this logic (functionA, functionB) in sub-classes:

```
public interface City {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class Example {

   private Map<String, City> cities;

   public void run(String param) {
       cities.get(param).doSomething();
   }
}
```

And then you define as many implementations for City as you need (London, Moscow ...) and you add instances of them to the map

Answer (score 1):

in C++, you can use std::map.
The code would be something like this-

```
typedef (void)(*funcPtr)(); //declaring a compatible function pointer

std::map<std::string, funcPtr> myFunctions;

myFunctions["london"]=functionA;
myFunctions["paris"]=functionB;
//etc etc...

//calling the function
string wantedCity="london";
myFunction[wantedCity]();
```

EDIT:
I see you removed C++ from tags. java has a similar container, you could look up it's methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect opportunity for an `enum`:

```
enum City {
    London {

        @Override
        void function() {
            System.out.println("Hello from England");
        }

    },
    Moscow  {

        @Override
        void function() {
            System.out.println("Hello from Russia");
        }

    },
    Delhi {

        @Override
        void function() {
            System.out.println("Hello from India");
        }

    };

    // They ALL must have a `function`.
    abstract void function ();
}

public void test() {
    City.valueOf("Moscow").function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, as long as you method returns a value. For example:

```
public SomeReturnType doSomthing(){
    return someReturnType;
}
```

and in your hashmap do the following

```
HashMap<String, SomeReturnType> hm = new HashMap<String, SomeReturnType>();
```

Boolean is probably the best option when comparing in a method.

Comment: THere's no need to create your own class, and actually what you show makes no sense. The standard way of doing this in Java is using the `Callable<V>` interface.

Comment: I'm not sure how this was relevant. I'm not creating a new class. Just defining a return type (SomeReturnType) just like your V.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Reflection. Just store the function name as value in the `HashMap`, then call it by`Method.invoke`.

[Class.getMethod(String name, Class... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

[Method.invoke(Object obj, Object... args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)